# Add Custom Product Attributes to Order Invoice

Tags: attributes, invoice

I would like to add 2 custom product attributes onto our order Invoice that gets emailed out to our customers.

Also it would be ok, if I can show parent and child product together.

Comment: Just to clarify you only want to change the invoice confirmation email content? Or do you also want to change all other representations of the invoice (admin invoice view, pdf and frontend customer view)? Also are your two custom attributes static (the same for all invoices) or are they variable per invoice?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, i want to change the invoice confirmation email content. and frontent customer view. The two custom attributes are variable per product sku.

Comment: Another option that would be the same affect for us. Is it possible to include the parent product (as well as the child product) on the invoice and customer view?

Answer (score 0):

First for the additional attribute in order confirmation email, take a look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258004/add-custom-attribute-variable-to-order-confirmation-e-mail-template. For the frontend customer view (i assume the url is this sales/order/view/order_id/some_id/), you need to override the template file located in **frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items.phtml**